# Does IntentService always finish if the application is stopped or crashes?

Tags: android, intentservice

I have an application that (on user prompt) will perform a long running operation and report back to the UI.

Right now I'm using a `Service` with `BroadcastReceivers` to do this work, I start the service , it does its job (on a different thread) and then broadcasts a signal that it has finished.

If the user wishes to stop the application (because they are bored or something) they can do this, and the operation will finish (which is what I want).

I saw that there is an `IntentService`, which always runs on its own thread once it receives an Intent , and uses `ResultReceiver` to send back results and progress (which frankly is much better for me than using a `BroadcastReceiver`)

My questions are these:

**a)** If the user closes the application, will the `IntentService` finish its work before closing?

**b)** If the above indeed happens, how can I debug the case of the application 
being closed and the `IntentService` still running? If I try to close the 
application while the `IntentService` is running then the service also stops.